# Query to list all duplicate records in a date range

Tags: sql, date, ms-access

I am a NOVICE so please respond in a "Dummies" format.
I  have a table that tracks all written warnings for my employees, I created a find duplicates query using the wizard and build a report. In my query I am need to list all records where the [EMPID] shows up more than 3 times.  In the date field I have it going back 90 days.   The report seems to do exactly what I need however is seems to randomly still list records that only have 1 or 2 entries in the last 90 days.  If I take the date criteria out, it works perfect, I can change it to look for 3,4,5 or any number and it works fine.  As soon as I add the date criteria I get mixed results.

```sql
SELECT [tble_Administrative Actions].FirstName,
       [tble_Administrative Actions].LastName,
       [tble_Administrative Actions].Category,
       [tble_Administrative Actions].Offense,
       [tble_Administrative Actions].EmpID,
       [tble_Administrative Actions].Date
FROM [tble_Administrative Actions]
INNER JOIN [HR Report Employee Master]
ON [tble_Administrative Actions].[EmpID] = [HR Report Employee Master].[EmployeeNumber]
WHERE (
    (([tble_Administrative Actions].EmpID) In (
        SELECT [EmpID]
        FROM [tble_Administrative Actions] As Tmp
        GROUP BY [EmpID]
        HAVING Count([EmpID]) > 3)
    )
    AND (([tble_Administrative Actions].Date) >= DateAdd("d", -90, Date()))
    AND (([HR Report Employee Master].CurrentStatusDescription) = "active")
)
ORDER BY [tble_Administrative Actions].EmpID,
         [tble_Administrative Actions].Date;
```

Comment: Hi desnyder. I edited your question to try to make your query more readable to others. You don't mention in the question what language you are using to write your query. You can add it by [edit]ing your question. Adding the right language tags can make it easier for the experts on Stack Overflow to find and answer your question.

Comment: Thank you Thomas - 
This is a MS Access query built with the query Wizard.

Comment: Thank you for the advise

Answer (score 0):

Your inner select query counts in the complete table. If you only want the records which have at least 3 occurrences in the last 90 days, then you have to add the date criteria to the inner select which counts the occurrences:

```
WHERE (
(([tble_Administrative Actions].EmpID) In (
    SELECT [EmpID]
    FROM [tble_Administrative Actions] As Tmp
    WHERE Tmp.Date >= DateAdd("d", -90, Date())
    GROUP BY [EmpID]
    HAVING Count([EmpID]) > 3)
)
AND (([tble_Administrative Actions].Date) >= DateAdd("d", -90, Date()))
AND (([HR Report Employee Master].CurrentStatusDescription) = "active")
```